# What's the differences between "quasi" and "semi"?

Tags: difference

I recently learned the word *quasi* and found it's very similar to *semi*. I looked up in the dictionary and found many examples, like *quasi-governmental*. Out of curiosity, I searched *"semi-governmental"* in Google books and the result surprised me. There are a lot of *"semi-governmental"* being used. What's the differences between *quasi* and *semi*? Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**semi-** literally means *half* (as in a "semi-detached house") while **quasi-** means *almost*. In common usage you can use either one interchangeably, and Wiktionary lists each one as a synonym for the other.

**Semi** as a noun refers to specific usages, like a semi-trailer or semi-detached house, and you would not use "quasi" in those places.